# How to verify the mouse hover message in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, hover, webdriver

I have tried to print the mouse hover message by using below code:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div"));   
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
WebElement toolTipElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div"));
String toolTipTxt = toolTipElement.getText();
System.out.println(toolTipTxt);
```

Actual result:

Hovered on the icon, not printing the hover message and it's get skipped to next.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_ please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the below code and it's working fine for me

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div")); 
        Actions action = new Actions(driver); action.moveToElement(element).build().perform(); 
    WebElement toolTipElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div")); if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Hover message")) { System.out.println("Available"); 
    } else
    {
    System.out.println("Not Available"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For printing a message that pop up when we hover mouse is basically title attribute in html. I have created a HTML file for your issue and have written code for the same.

**HTML CODE :**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>StackOverFlow Problems </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Hovering get Text</h2>
<span title="hoverin' words">This will show tool-tip</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Selenium code to get hover message and printing it.

**Selenium + java code :**

```
public class HoverGetText {

    static WebDriver driver;
    static WebDriverWait wait;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        driver.get("C:\\Users\\HunteR\\Desktop\\Automation\\abc.html");
        String hoverValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='This will show tool-tip']")).getAttribute("title");
        System.out.println(hoverValue);
        }
 }
```

That's it ! you can call getAttribute(String args0) method on a WebElement and provide required HTML attribute.

Please let me know if you have any concerns.

Comment: I have tried the above code but it's redirecting to the file path(html file path)

Comment: create a folder anywhere in your system and paste the html code in a file and rename that file to abc.html , and in driver.get("give the full path of abc.html ") , hope that'll help you !

Comment: Yes even I also tried with the same steps mentioned by you, but it was redirecting to the browser and searching for the file path

Comment: redirecting to the browser ? I didn't get this point ! where have you placed your html file ?

Comment: I have placed in "d folder" and while run the script it's opening the browser and fetching the html file path in url section of browser

Comment: So is it not able to fetch or what ?

Comment: I have used the below code                                                                       driver.get("D:\\hover.html");                                                                         String hoverValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div")).getAttribute("title");
 System.out.println(hoverValue);
it's fetching the "file:///D:/hover.html" and showing as file not found but file is available in corresponding folder

Comment: driver.get("D://some folder/abc.html") ? what is the output of this line?

Comment: Before running this code I have logged in the application but after executing this opened browser application get closed and trying to fetch the following file path "file:///D:/hover.html" in the browser
Actually from this stage how it will get continued because it was logged out from application trying to fetch the html file path

Comment: @YaswanthG : the HTML code I have provided with that what you have to do is create a .html file and place in your D directory , then use the given code and in that put driver.get("D://hover.html") , I hope that'll help

Comment: Yes I have did the same

Comment: Still you are not able to open hover.html using selenium ?

Comment: Yes html file opened and showing title as "Hovering get Text" and body text as "This will show tool-tip".
But I want check the hover message inside the tool tip. How it become possible? because after the reading the file it executing next line i.e "String hoverValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div")).getAttribute("title");"

Already "logged in" application got closed, before executing the hover reading line "logged in" application got closed,so how come it will read the hover message

Comment: Actual scenario i want to automate

Steps
1.Launch the url
2.Click on the login
3.Verify the hover message near the username

Comment: use this code after driver.get("D://hovber.html")  ;  String hoverValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='This will show tool-tip']")).getAttribute("title");
        System.out.println(hoverValue);

Comment: Can you provide the URL ?

Comment: Actual solution I need
1.I need to login the web application 
2.Click on the login button and it will redirect to login page
3.In login page, I want verify the hover message of information icon that is placed near user name text box. I hope @cruisepandey you have understood my scenario.

Comment: Can you provide the URL ?

Comment: This url I can't provide. You can use some demo login, which has mouse hover in login page

Comment: I can't write the code then ! it'd be only assumptions ! 1. I want verify the hover message of information icon that is placed near user name text box for this you have to use getAttribute() method

Comment: I have used the below code and its working fine
'WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div"));   
 Actions action = new Actions(driver);
  action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
  WebElement toolTipElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div"));
    if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Hover message"))
    {
System.out.println("Available");
}
    else{System.out.println("Not Available");
}'