# How to get mouse hover message in selenium webdriver which is not given in HTML

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[image: Image from URL - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775715/how-to-verify-the-mouse-hover-message-in-selenium]

I want to get the text of the message which appears on hovering the mouse over any text or info icon.

Comment: There are various ways to fetch the tool-tip depending on the application type. Can you please share the URL if it is public? If not at least the HTML mark-up? Also, share the code trials and error trace.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution in  Python. You can replicate it in Java, pretty straightforward.

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

driver = Chrome(options=options)
# Here I've taken the URL of this same stackoverflow page
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75945977/how-to-get-mouse-hover-message-in-selenium-webdriver-which-is-not-given-in-html")
time.sleep(1)
# and lets for example, take the java tag in your post
element_to_hover_over = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="question"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[1]')
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
hover.perform()
time.sleep(2)
hover_tag_all_detail = element_to_hover_over.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.esc-remove').text
print(f"all details:\n{hover_tag_all_detail}")
hover_tag_descrition = element_to_hover_over.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.fc-light').text
print(f"tag description only:\n{hover_tag_descrition}")
```

output:

```
all details:
2.1m watchers 1.9m questions
Java is a high-level object-oriented programming language. Use this tag when you're having problems using or understanding the language itself. This tag is frequently used alongside other tags for libraries and/or frameworks used by Java developers. View tag

tag description only:
Java is a high-level object-oriented programming language. Use this tag when you're having problems using or understanding the language itself. This tag is frequently used alongside other tags for libraries and/or frameworks used by Java developers. View tag
```

Comment: I am trying to use this in my application but it not giving me the text, the content is inside the angular component. Is there any other way to get the text of Angular component